# simple boolean question

Tags: java, boolean, operator-precedence

What am I doing wrong here?

I am wanting to display integers from 1-100 who are divisible by either 6 or 7.  That's done and working.  The next step is to not display any that are divisible by both...that isn't working in my loop (those integers are still displaying)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    if (i % 6 == 0 || i % 7 == 0 && i % (6 * 7) != 0){
        println(i);
    }
```

Thanks!
Joel

Comment: Java Operator Precedence: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html#nutsandbolts-precedence

Comment: Cool.  Thanks!  I was mistakenly separating the three arguments in my head and not thinking parenthesis were needed...

Comment: you are not the same Joel as `http://www.joelonsoftware.com/`, right

Comment: @Rakesh: that Joel is: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky. Somehow I doubt he'd get confused over precedence.

Comment: Indeed we are different people...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try making your condition more explicit by adding (...), like so:

```
if (((i % 6 == 0 || i % 7 == 0) && (i % (6 * 7) != 0)) {
}
```

by default && takes precedence over ||

Comment: in general, dont ever assume anything about order of evaluation or "stickiness" of logical operators, always add (...)

Answer (score 3):

Missing parentheses:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    if ((i % 6 == 0 || i % 7 == 0) && i % (6 * 7) != 0) {
        println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply stop worrying about how to evaluate precedence, and use something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if ((i % 42) == 0) continue;
    if ((i %  6) == 0) println (i);
    if ((i %  7) == 0) println (i);
}
```

I'm assuming here that 1-100 was an inclusive range in which case you should use `<=` rather than `<`. It won't matter for your specific case since 100 is divisible by neither 6 nor 7.

Guess what? Any decent optimising compiler (including JIT ones) will probably end up generating the same code as for all the other possibilities. And, even if it didn't, it wouldn't matter unless you were calling this function a great *many* times.

I think that's a tiny bit more readable than:

```
if (i % 6 == 0 || i % 7 == 0 && i % (6 * 7) != 0) ...
```

or, worse yet, the Lisp-like thing you'll have to turn it into to get it working properly :-)

---

Keep in mind one possibility - you can change your loop to make it more efficient (sevenfold), for the specific case with 6 and 7,  thus:

```
for (int i = 7; i <= 100; i += 7)
    if ((i % 6) != 0)
        println (i);
```

This uses the `for` loop itself to only check multiples of 7 and print them if they're *not* also multiples of 6.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the exclusive or

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        if ((i % 6 == 0) ^ (i % 7 == 0)) {
            println(i);
        }
    }
```

or just an unequal `if ((i % 6 == 0) != (i % 7 == 0))`
Since exclusive or is not used that often, I doubt this will increase the readability of the code...

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
if ((i % 6 == 0 || i % 7 == 0) && !(i % 6 == 0 && i % 7 == 0)){
    println(i);
}
```

Comment: This does NOT compile! Wrong position of the closing parenthesis here `(i % 6 == 0 || i % 7) == 0` should be `(i % 6 == 0 || i % 7 == 0)`